# Any/some in a specific sentence

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I know that some/any are used with plural (with some exceptions), but what about this?

> I can give you a book...if there is any

Is that correct? I want to say that if there is any book, I will give it to him.

And what about plural?

> I can give you the books...if there are some

Or should it be "any?

Comment: I would say "I can give you a book if there is one" and "I can give you books if there are any".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentences will be more natural if they read:

*I can give you a book... if there is one.*

**One** here functions as a pronoun in order to avoid repeating *a book*. *Any book* means *it doesn't matter which one*, as in the sentence "Take any book you want".

*I can give you the books... if there are any.*

Since the *if* clause expresses uncertainty, the use of **any** sounds better to my ears.

Comment: Thanks, regarding the first sentence, yes I would like to express "if there is any", meaning whatever book..Not sure from your comment whether it is not correct?

Comment: @Pietro: In that case you should say: "I can give you any book that's left" or "I can give you any book I'll find." The way you suggest doesn't express the meaning you want.